# Direct URL to Specific Slide

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

I am using a slider called mySlider, or SL_Slider..

It uses the MooTools library...

If i am on the page with the slider, there is a simple script for the href that calls the appropriate slide..

```
<a href="javascript:mySlider.numPress(3);">link</a>
```

I believe this script is supposed to have the ability to also allow for a specific slide to load if the page in question is accessed via a URL link (from another page). There is a function that looks to be looking for a "passedID" variable (pasted below).

My problem is that i can't seem to figure out how to pass this variable to the script via a URL (or even if that's possible)...

I've tried all sort of combos and no luck...

Here is an example I tried (plus a ton of others):  www.website.com?passedID=3

Any help would be much appreciated!

(If there is any additional info required, i am happy to paste it.

Thanks.

Mac

```
slideIt: function(passedID) {

        var self = this;

        //get item to slide out
        var curItem = self.options.items[self.options.itemNum]; 
        if(self.options.numNavActive == true){
            var curNumItem =  self.numNav[self.options.itemNum];
        }

        //check for passedID presence
        if(passedID != null) {
            if(self.options.itemNum != passedID){
                if(self.options.itemNum > passedID) { 
                    self.direction = 0; 
                } else { 
                    self.direction = 1;
                }
                self.options.itemNum = passedID;
            }
        }
        else{
            self.changeIndex(); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var slide_num_in_url = document.location.hash.split("#").join("");
mySlider.numPress(slide_num_in_url);
```

---

**EDIT:**

Call when the page loads.

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var slide_num_in_url = document.location.hash.split("#").join("");
    mySlider.numPress(slide_num_in_url);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Makrem.. though i wasn't exactly sure where to enter this code, i did play with it.. was unable to get this working, likely do to my lack ofjavascript knowledge... i did play with this and substituted slide_num_in_url for passedID ... i eliminated the second line... This worked to get me to the correct slide on the page -- however, by doing so it locked up the slide system so it will only display the passedID slide number -- this happens even if you click NEXT or BACK, so by using the passedID, it makes the <a href="javascript:mySlider.numPress(3);">link</a> inoperable.....

Comment: it's back to the drawing board for me... I sincerely appreciate your assistance!

Comment: Don't change your code that way. My lines should be run when the page loads. So, check my edited answer for a sample.

Comment: Makram, thank you for the new code.. i placed it at the very top of the page under the opening head tag inside of <script> tags.. It works great on Firefox -- but Chrome and IE do not go to the appropriate slide! I realize you are busy, so i hate to bother with this and feel free to call this one quits, as it is looking like this may not work... this is the URL to the original script: http://stoutlabs.com/demos/class_slider_v2b/index.htm   in case you are interested... thanks for everything you've done thus far.

Comment: Try this line instead: `var slide_num_in_url = document.location.href.split("#").join("");` *href* instead of hash.

Comment: Makram, thanks again. no luck on this one either... I am thinking this might require a professional, and I am certainly not that , to handle this.. I posted a job req at on of the freelance sites to find a guru for this. Again, your help has been invaluable. thank you.